# Why doesn't SQL have standardized metadata queries?

Tags: sql, standards

I was trying to find a way to query the columns in a table of a SQL database. This seems like a reasonable functionality to expect, but I found that it is largely implementation dependent. For example:

SQLite:

```
PRAGMA table_info(<table name>)
```

SQL Server:

```
SELECT name 
FROM sys.columns 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('table name')
```

MySQL:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM database_Name.table_name
```

I then found that there is an ANSI standard query to do this:

```
select column_name 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where table_name = 'table name'
```

But not every RDBMS (including SQLite) implements `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, so it doesn't seem like a reliable option.

Why is there not an enforced standard SQL statement I can guarantee will work to give me back metadata like columns in a table in the same way I can guarantee `SELECT * FROM <table name>` will work with any SQL database?

Comment: aslong as every company and group can implement only parts of the sql standard, you will always need a wrapper for every database